# CakePHP: How is redirect managed if there are more than one steps?

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I would like to know how to manage redirect with multiple steps?

Example:

1. Search for something
2. click on a result
3. click on a color for this result
4. click to submit choice
5. autoredirected to the search

Solutions:

1. I can pass manually the `?redirectUrl=/search?query=tshirt` (with the appropriate url encoding) through each step, but this seems very ugly solution. Or maybe there is a way to automate it?
2. I could save the redirectUrl in the Session and extend the redirect function to always check for session variable `redirectUrl` before redirecting, but the problem is: what happens if someone quits at step 4? The session variable stays and will redirect if person hits a page with redirect at a completely different place.

It would be awesome if I got the answer of someone experienced!

Answer (score 1):

I think using session isn't a bad choice.  As for question #2, you can expect for each page in the sequence you describe, that if the user is following normal page navigation, they arrived from a certain action and controller.  So, delete the redirectUrl session variable if the controller's `$this->referer()` does not match what you'd expect, and redirect them to the beginning of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Do below four steps in one go using simple hide and show javascript or using ajax calls

```
Search for something - create one form with query text box
click on a result - show color options
click on a color for this result - select color
click to submit choice - execute step 5
```

Step: After that you have search string and color now you can redirect to the search action easily!